# Android AppAuth send password to Chrome Tab

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, keycloak, appauth

I'm looking to incorporate the AppAuth library into my app. Currently there is already a method for users to log in and authenticate to servers. The apps API is being phased out and a new one is being phased in. As part of this, all new endpoints will need to be authenticated with AppAuth, whilst old endpoints will still need to be authenticated with the current log in system. To achieve this I need to show the existing log in screen, which takes an email address and password. I'm able to pass the users email address to the AppAuth library using the `AuthorizationRequest.Builder` `setLoginHint` method.

With the above implementation the user needs to type their password twice, which is quite cumbersome. My question is, is there a way to also pass the users password, securely, to the AppAuth tab?